# Opening a Lync Chat from application

Tags: c#, lync

I have ListViews that generate ListViewItems containing employee names. I want to be able to click these ListViewItems and have it open a Lync chat window. I found that a Lync Chat can be open via an html link

```
im:<sip:username@domain.com>
```

I tested this and it works however i want to use the contact name rather than the SIP address.
The names match the Contact name in Lync exactly so i'm hoping there's way to just say,

`Open Lync chat containing "name"`

any insight?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj937298(v=office.15).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

SIP address is ID of each employee , you must use SIP , there might be many employee with the same name , then ChatWith("John Doe") , which one?